Python files do not run automatically in GitHub actions
I want to have GitHub Actions run Python code at the same time every week.
There is a 'main.py' file in GitHub's 'problem_sending' repository, and a 'main.yalm' file in the 'problem_sending/.github/workflows/' path.
The Python file runs properly when run alone in visual studio, but when you try to run it through a GitHub action, it does not work.
To briefly explain the contents of the Python code, the name of the problem on the Programmers site is emailed to friends every week.
In order to send emails using Gmail, I also obtained an app password and set it in GitHub settings.
The contents of the yalm file are as follows.
name: Weekly Coding Challenges Email

on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '*/60 * * * *'

jobs:
  send_email:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      EMAIL_USER: ${{ secrets.EMAIL_USER }}
      EMAIL_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.EMAIL_PASSWORD }}
    steps:
    - name: Check out repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up Python
      uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: 3.8
    - name: Install Python dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install requests
    - name: Run Python script
      run: python main.py

The contents of the Python file are as follows:
import requests
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
import os

current_indices = {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0}

def fetch_problems_by_level(level):
    url = f"https://school.programmers.co.kr/api/v2/school/challenges/?perPage=20&levels[]={level}&order=recent&search=&page=1"
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()
        return [problem['title'] for problem in data['result']]
    else:
        print(f"Failed to fetch data: HTTP {response.status_code}")
        return []

def send_email(subject, body, to_addr, from_addr, password):
    smtp_server = "smtp.gmail.com"
    smtp_port = 587

    message = MIMEMultipart()
    message["From"] = from_addr
    message["To"] = to_addr
    message["Subject"] = subject
    message.attach(MIMEText(body, "plain"))

    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, smtp_port)
        server.starttls()  # TLS 보안 시작
        server.login(from_addr, password)

        server.sendmail(from_addr, to_addr, message.as_string())
        
        print("이메일이 성공적으로 전송되었습니다.")
    except Exception as e:
        print("이메일 전송에 실패하였습니다:", e)
    finally:
        # 연결 종료
        server.quit()

def get_problems_text():
    problems_text = "<<<오늘의 코테 문제>>>\n"
    levels_count = {0: 2, 1: 2, 2: 1}
    for level, count in levels_count.items():
        problems = fetch_problems_by_level(level)
        start_index = current_indices[level]
        end_index = start_index + count
        selected_problems = problems[start_index:end_index]
        current_indices[level] += count
        if selected_problems:
            problems_text += f"{level} - " + ", ".join(selected_problems) + "\n"
    return problems_text

def main():
    from_addr = os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER')
    password = os.environ.get('EMAIL_PASSWORD')
    to_addr_list = [
        ("ㅁㄴㅇ", "abcd@naver.com"),
        ("ㅋㅌㅊ", "qwer@gmail.com"),
        ("ㅈㅂㄷ", "bfaf0@naver.com"),
        
    ]
    subject = "이번주 코테 문제"
    problems_text = get_problems_text()
    for recipient_name, recipient_email in to_addr_list:
        send_email(subject, problems_text, recipient_email, from_addr, password)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

I wish you could tell me what the problem is.
I created the yalm file and py file as written above, and configured the GitHub repository, but the email was not sent.
Even if you go into GitHub's action, no record is left, so you can't figure out what the problem is.
If I modify the EMAIL_USER and EMAIL_PASSWORD contents of the Python file and run it alone, the email is sent normally.
I don't know why it doesn't work only with GitHub Action.

When you say "no record is left", do you mean that there is no run of this workflow in the list of workflow runs? If so, maybe your cron expression is wrong? It's running every 60th minute, not once per week. It's equivalent to 0 * * * *, but I'm not sure if */60 is valid. Also, try adding a workflow_dispatch trigger so you can manually start a run.
